# Regular expression to match uppercase phrases with some of which have lowercase words in between

Tags: regex

How can I match (with one regex) uppercase phrases some of which have lowercase words in between? Example:

1). "The following months are casual JUNE, JULY, and AUGUST while all others are not."

```
my match should be: "UPPERCASEWORD1, UPPERCASEWORD2, lowercaseword, UPPERCASEWORD3" (i.e.**JUNE, JULY, and AUGUST**) <=== uppercase words with lowercase in between
```

2) "the office is closed SATURDAY TO MONDAY thank you."

my match should be "**SATURDAY TO MONDAY**" (i.e "UPPERCASEWORD1 UPPERCASEWORD2 UPPERCASEWORD3")  <== all uppercase

In simple terms, I am looking for a regex that would match a phrase which starts and ends with uppercase words but that could also have lowercase words in the middle.

I need one regex which can do both. 
Thanks!

Comment: How much lowercase do you want to allow in between? Which non-alphanumerics should be allowed? Which language or tool are you using? And what have you tried?

Comment: What are those "*some lowercase prepositions*"? And why does it need to be a regex?

Comment: Thanks guys for the response!I have tried \b[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)*\b which works great if the entire phrase is in upper cases. but some of my phrases that I need to match have lower case words in between. The good thing is the phrases start and end in upper case words … I mean fully upper case not the first char in upper. And when there are lower cases in between, this regex matches them separately not as one phrase and filters out the intermediary lowercase word. I want it to be greedy and select everything in-between two uppercase words. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regular expressions don’t recognize the English language**. So it doesn't have an idea about prepositions and punctuation. But you can define a rule that is understandable by a regex.

Like this *It should match any number of upper case letters and commas which can be combined with `N` number of lower case characters*. Assuming the number of lower case characters will hold all the preposition.

```
([A-Z]+[\sa-z,]{0,N})+[A-Z]+
```

Another approach would be if you have a list of preposition you can use it in the regex.

```
([A-Z]+((in|out|or|by|with|and)*[\s,]*)+)+[A-Z]+
```

But this list is not reliable as you don’t know which word will act as preposition. In English any word can act as preposition. It depends on where it's used.

Comment: I mean lower case words in between uppercase words. I don't really mean necessarily prepositions. I should edit my question.

Comment: The above examples and are not working, because they are also matching words outside the upper case boudaries, so in my example, the lower case words before and after the upper case phrases are being matched. That is not what I was asking. I have edited my question. Thanks you!

Comment: Both of the expression will match. I have updated. For first expression you need to set a value for `N`. If `N=10` it'll be like `{0,10}`.

Comment: ([A-Z]+[\sa-z,]{0,9})+[A-Z]+ matches all upper and lower case words and even entire sentence. I have updated my question. My question was not as clear as it should have been. I actually want my match to start and end with only uppercase words. It should completely exclude all lowercase words from the start and end but it should allow lowercase words in the middle.

Comment: How are you testing this regex using which tool?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/376535/shiplu-mokadd-im   Thank you very much! Actually, it works, it was here on my end that case insensitivty was turned on. I apologize. It does work!! Thank You again!!

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\b[A-Z]+\b[-,\s]+((and|or|is|on|at|to)\s+)*)*\b[A-Z]+\b/g
             ^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              |              |
 list of delimiters    list of prepositions
```

will match them, for example. Please note that your requirements are very vague, but you could easily replace the list of prepositions with a general matching like `[a-z]+`.

Comment: I agree my question was vague. I have edited it. The above regex is not working. I have edited my posting. Thanks!!